# CSS / jQuery Menus not working in IE7

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, debugging

I'm sure there's a million questions along this line but I can't find one that relates to my specific issue.  After wrestling with IE7 for countless hours I finally have the text showing above the video content (classic IE7 z-index bug - squashed now).

You'll need to have a look at this site in either Firefox / Chrome / Safari first:

http://valeriaentertainment.com.s66112.gridserver.com/

Hovering over "Gallery" or "About" in the navigation will reveal an animated jQuery `slideUp()` / `slideDown()` dropdown menu.  For some reason, now that the CSS is fixed the background for the dropdowns is not visible in IE7.

Any debug suggestions / IE7 hacks? ;)

**EDIT:**

I should note that I **think** this is a javscript issue because the animation does not seem to be happening as expected (view site in a good browser)...

Here is the relevant JS code the `js-enabled` class is to allow the menus to work via CSS only in case javascript is disabled:

```
//jQuery slideDown for menu dropdowns
$('.menu').addClass('js-enabled');

$('.js-enabled li').hoverIntent(function () {
   $(this).find(".sub-menu").stop(true,true).slideDown(400);
 }, 
 function () {
   $(this).find(".sub-menu").stop(true,true).slideUp(400);
});
```

Comment: I know it's not much of a consolation. But it is working fine in IE9

Comment: How come I never get bellydancing companies as clients?

Comment: @RSG - LOL! Insult to injury!!!  Maybe next time I should say that I'm developing a site for my bellydancing company... I'd have to change my avatar / username but I think I'd get LOADS of helpful fellows tripping over each other to debug my sites then ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm poking around a bit and IE doesn't seem to register the CSS property for the background image.
What happens if you add quotes into your background:url property:

```
.sub-menu li{
  background: url('images/sub-menu_middle.jpg') top left repeat-y;
  ...
}
```

**Edit**

As you said, the older IE is picky about it's spaces.  Added a space between `)` and `top` in the CSS

Comment: Thanks!  I also figured out just now that it's CSS and not javascript.  I added quotes as per your suggestion but no dice :/ ... I'll tell you this, I think it's a z-index buggy IE7 behavior because all the other background URLs are also lacking quotes but they are fine in IE7... Any other ideas?

Comment: Ahhhhhhhhhhhhhhh!!!!! `url(images/sub-menu_middle.jpg)top left no-repeat` was lacking a space after the closing ) ... HATE!

Comment: No I fixed it now!!! Just edit your answer to mention the lack of SPACE after ... `middle.jpg)top` You were basically right, just that it wasn't the quotes, it was the stupid missing SPACE

Comment: Honestly thank you!  Amazing what a second pair of eyes can do for you!

Comment: Happy to help.  I've certainly received plenty of it on this site- I love it.